# Nav bar background image in iOS moves once back buttons are added

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ios8

I've added an image to my nav bar.  Works great until you link to another view and the back button causes the image to then have a small amount of white space below it.  Also it causes the image to shift to the left and no longer be centered.  Is there a way to fix this image to be permanently centered and to not have white space on the bottom?

Thanks

SC

Comment: You are using storyboard or adding nav bar programmatically?

Comment: I used code. `override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // 1
        var nav = self.navigationController?.navigationBar
        // 2
        nav?.barStyle = UIBarStyle.Default
        // 3
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 374, height: 88))
        imageView.contentMode = .ScaleAspectFit
        // 4
        let image = UIImage(named: "nav-background-image")
        imageView.image = image
        // 5
        navigationItem.titleView = imageView`